# Does double have a greater range than long?

Tags: c#, types, size

In an article on MSDN, it states that the `double` data type has a range of "-1.79769313486232e308 .. 1.79769313486232e308". Whereas the `long` data type only has a range of "-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 .. 9,223,372,036,854,775,807". How can a `double` hold so much more data than a `long` if they are both 64 bits in size?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: It's all about precision, or lack thereof: [IEEE Floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Longs actually store the number, whereas floats store a scientific representation of the number that's relatively imprecise.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The number of possible doubles, and the number of possible longs is the same, they are just distributed differently*.

The longs are uniformly distributed, while the floats are not. You can Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point).

I'd write more, but for some reason the cursor is jumping around all over the place on my phone.

Edit: This might actually be more helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#section_1

Edit2: and this is even better: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2010/05/07/fun-with-floating-point.aspx

* *According to that link, it would seem that there are actually more longs, since some doubles are lost due to the way NaNs and other special numbers are represented.*

Answer (score 15):

A simple answer is that `double` is only accurate to 15-16 total digits, as opposed to `long` which (as an integer type) has an *absolute accuracy* within an *explicit digit limit*, in this case 19 digits. (Keep in mind that *digits* and *values* are semantically different.)

`double`: -/+ 0.000,000,000,000,01 to +/- 99,999,999,999,999.9
(at 100% accuracy, with a loss in accuracy starting from 16th digit, as represented in "-1.79769313486232e308 .. 1.79769313486232e308".)

`long`: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807

`ulong`: 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (1 more digit than long, but identical value range (since it's only been shifted to exclude negative returns).

In general, int-type **real numbers** are preferred over floating-point **decimal values**, unless you explicitly need a decimal representation (for whichever purpose).

---

In addition, you may know that **signed** are preferred over **unsigned**, since the former is much less bug-prone (consider the statement `uint i;`, then `i - x;` where `x > i`).

Answer (score 11):

`long` is a signed 64-bit integer value and `double` is a 64-bit floating point value. Looking at their FCL types might make more sense. `long` maps to `System.Int64` and `double` maps to `System.Double`.